# Getting the color of a pixel drawn by DWM in C#

Tags: c#, colors, screenshot, pixel, dwm

I want to get Screenshots of a possible hidden Window of another application that is using drawing via direct3d or opengl. I tryed a lot of ways to receive this windows content but only got black or transparent pictures. The closest i got was by using a DWM sample here
http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/10/05/4495.aspx
this paints the window onto my c# form but i cant get the pixelcolors. If ill do a form.drawtobitmap the pixels drawn by dwm are missing.

So is their any way to use DWM to recive the capture into a image
or to get the image drawn onto my form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question:
You can use GetPixel() Win32 function. But it's overkill in this situation.

[Pinvoke GetPixel](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32/getpixel.html)

[MSDN GetPixel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The right way, is to get the device context and bit blit the content.

**EDIT:**

I've thrown together some code, by using PrintWindow. Seems to work quite well, even with media players. Note that GetWindowRect returns invalid rectangle for minimized Windows. But it's a decent start.

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Rect
    {
        internal Rect(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
        {
            Left = left;
            Top = top;
            Right = right;
            Bottom = bottom;
        }

        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hDC, uint nFlags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, out Rect lpRect);

    public void DumpWindow(IntPtr hwndSource, string filename)
    {
        Rect rc;
        GetWindowRect(hwndSource, out rc);

        var bmp = new Bitmap(rc.Right - rc.Left, rc.Bottom - rc.Top, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        using (Graphics gBmp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            IntPtr hdcBmp = gBmp.GetHdc();

            PrintWindow(hwndSource, hdcBmp, 0);

            gBmp.ReleaseHdc(hdcBmp);
        }

        bmp.Save(filename);
    }
```

**Edit2:**
And if you add a second button to DWM demo form, insert this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var w = (Window)lstWindows.SelectedItem;
    DumpWindow(w.Handle, "test.bmp");
    Process.Start("test.bmp");
}
```

It still shows an empty image?

Comment: thanks for the getpixelhint i can now retrieve the color of the projected rectangle but i will give the bit blit a look too.

Comment: ok i tryed the bit blit method and the code you postet but both show show the same results. It should look like this http://imgur.com/07kPulZ,Hj9HSX7 (taken with windows just by using the printkey) but it ends up looking like this http://imgur.com/07kPulZ,Hj9HSX7#1

Comment: And the dumped file looks like? Try out the code in edit2, and report back.

Comment: great that you still try to help i have tryed the code and it looks like this
source http://imgur.com/VsVXb9h,fjYl2An,gKaLMal
dwmwindow http://imgur.com/VsVXb9h,fjYl2An,gKaLMal#1
result http://imgur.com/VsVXb9h,fjYl2An,gKaLMal#2

the capturesource is a virtual machine showing a emulated android. I think the display is rendered in opengl thats properbly the reason its so hard to capture and i was so happy that dwm nearly did the job (i got it on my own form)